# Como ordeno una matriz por columna y junto también su respectiva fila

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Tengo una matriz así

```
[6.124,-75.946,55]
[6.125,-75.966,44]
[6.135,-75.976,12] 
[6.144,-75.846,45]
```

quiero ordenarla de menor a mayor según la ultima columna, quedaría algo así

```
[6.135,-75.976,12] 
[6.125,-75.966,44]
[6.144,-75.846,45]
[6.124,-75.946,55]
```

He recurrido al foro por que llevo mucho tiempo intentándolo, he estado leyendo documentación pero no lo he podido lograr, lo mas cercano a lo que he llegado fue usando el método `numpy.sort(matriz, axis=0)` pero con este método me ordena la ultima columna pero a su vez me desordena junto a sus respectiva fila.

Comment: y que haz intentado? cual es tu avance? o simplemente quieres que te resolvamos el ejercicio?. Recomiendo que leas [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Lo puedes hacer de  una forma con la función `sorted()`, esta función recibe un parámetro `key` en el cual le podemos indicar en base a que va a ordenar, en este caso usaremos una `lambda` donde indicaremos que ordene según el ultimo elemento, si aplicamos la función a la *matriz* lo que reciba la `lambda` será cada una de las listas. Y para indicar el ultimo elemento lo hacemos con `[-1]`

```
#matriz valida en python
matriz = [[6.124,-75.946,55],
[6.125,-75.966,44],
[6.135,-75.976,12], 
[6.144,-75.846,45]]

#funcion sorted()
matriz_ord = sorted(matriz, key=lambda x: x[-1])
print(matriz_ord)
```

**resultado**

```
[[6.135, -75.976, 12],
 [6.125, -75.966, 44],
 [6.144, -75.846, 45],
 [6.124, -75.946, 55]]
```